# How 2 reload the page in smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt

I want to refresh page after click on save button.

Can anybody please tell me, how to do it in smartgwt?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gwt's window class. See this on how to do it-

[How to reload web page in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256494/how-to-reload-web-page-in-gwt)

Make sure u reference gwt's `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window` class and not smartgwts `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window` class

`Window.Location.reload()` is what you will have to call.